# how to get a text from textbox that is betwen two dots

Tags: c#, text-manipulation

i just want to get a text from textbox that is betwen two dots for example. www. abc.org . h

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on what you are trying to do and why? txtTextBox.Text gives you the entered text, and then its all about parsing...

Comment: Please be more precise. Do you just want text that is between two dots with prefix and suffix or do you want to parse an URL (or something even more complex like www.google.com/search?q=test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be a bit more specific with your question I think. Now, if you're just looking to extract the middle part of the address, something like the following should do the job:

```
var parts = textbox.Text.Split(new char[] {'.'});
if (parts.Length < 3) throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid address.");
var middlePart = parts[1];
```

Comment: how to get a text from textbox that is betwen two dots

Answer (score 2):

in C#

```
string url = "www.google.com";
string[] split_strings = url.Split('.');
Console.WriteLine(split_strings[1]);
```

Get String From Textbox:

```
string url = textbox_url.Text;
string[] split_strings = url.Split('.');
Console.WriteLine(split_strings[1]);
```

But please, use try and catch ;)

Comment: I can spot three compiler errors just from glancing at that code!

Comment: how to get a text from textbox that is betwen two dots

Answer (score 0):

string haystack= "www.google.com";
            string needle = "google";

```
        string myWord = GetWordFromString(haystack, needle);

        private string GetWordFromString(string haystack, string needle)
        {
           if (haystack.ToLower().Contains(needle))
           {
               return needle;
           }
        }
```

I re-read the post with comments I can see that you probably don't know what word you are going to extract... I think the first answer is the one that you are looking fore.

There's also regular expressions for extracting the domainname out of a url if that is your specific need.
Something like this:

```
    public static string ExtractDomainName(string Url)
    {
        return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
        Url,
        @"^([a-zA-Z]+:\/\/)?([^\/]+)\/.*?$",
        "$2"
        );
    }
```

Comment: I think, the google string was just an example, there's probably a need for a generic solution, i.e. by splitting the the string using the '.' as separator, or using real regex

Comment: how to get a text from textbox that is betwen two dots

Comment: ankush are there always only two dots in your text in the textbox?

Comment: The first answer by rAyt will solve that. However if someone enters something like "some.funny.looking.string" his code will return "funny" or something like "actually.. go see www.google.com" that will return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Is that as specific as your requirement is?

does it only have to work for www.SOMESITE.com

what about other tld extensions like, .net, .org, .co.uk, .ie etc...
what about other subdomains like, www2., api., news. etc...
what about domains with no subdomain like, google.com, theregister.co.uk, bit.ly

if that's a simple as your requirement is,

then

```
textBox.Text.Replace("www.", "").Replace(".com", "");
```

though I've a feeling you haven't thought through or fully explained your requirements.

If it is a more complex scenario, you might want to look at Regular expressions.

Comment: how to get a text from textbox that is betwen two dots

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "www. abc.org . h";
int left = Math.Max(text.IndexOf('.'), 0),
   right = Math.Min(text.LastIndexOf('.'), text.Length - 1);

string result = text.Substring(left+1, right - left-1).Trim();
```